# Aptana Studio 3 - Browsing for Custom Workspace Directory Crashes Program

Tags: php, crash, aptana

Just installed AS:3 and every time I load the program, it asks me to create a workspace and already has a path to a workspace directory the program wishes to create.

However, I would like to specify my own custom directory location but each time I click on the "browse" button to browse for a custom directory, the program immediately crashes with no error or warning message.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *not* running Windows (and maybe if you are, but I can't test that), create a link from where you really want your workspace to the place Aptana wants to put it.

The command will look something like:

```
ln -s /where/your/real/workspacearea/is  /home/youruser/Documents/Aptana
```

... just replace with the real home-dir and desired-workspace paths.

You will note that if you go to Window->Preferences->Startup and Shutdown->Workspaces, there is no "add" button - so no way to fix this within the running-program, either (in v3.3.2).

In later versions, this bug is "fixed" - but opening and closing tiny files can take 10 seconds or longer (gets worse the longer Aptana / your linux-login is open), and saving preferences makes the program crash on 'ok'.  I'm sticking with v3.3.2 (standalone) for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this in windows, try running AS in administrator mode, like so:

1. Hold down the SHIFT key, and right click on the AS icon to bring up the menu
2. Select "Run as Administrator"
3. See if the program still crashes.

Comment: @ nmagerko - Nothing but this is where their website sends you to post questions regarding their software. I thought it was weird myself, but hey, I go where I'm sent. If I'm wrong about this and have been clicking the wrong button, then I apologize.

@ Gopal Nair - Thank you, I'll give it a shot.